# Create topic with partitions from Spring-Cloud Binder

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I've a kafka configuration inside of my yaml file and for one input I'm adding multiple topics with different name. I want 3 of them to have 5 partitions and one of them must have 1 partition. How can I set it in my configuration file separately? Kafka version is old and it can't create partitions automatically so I need to make them manually.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        group: xxxx
        consumer:
          partitioned: true
          concurrency: 5
      kafka:
        binder:
          configuration:
            max.poll.interval.ms: 100000
            max.poll.records: 100
          brokers: xx.xx.xx.xx
          defaultBrokerPort: 8080
          replicationFactor: 1
      function:
        definition: methodName
      bindings:
        methodName-in-0:
          destination: topic1, topic2, topic3, topic4
```

Comment: Spring-Kafka can use `@Bean NewTopic` methods for this.

Comment: _Kafka version is old and it can't create partitions automatically_ - Brokers have always been able to auto-create topics with `num.partitions` defined in `server.properties`. But if you want different value of partitions, then you always needed to create manually. Version therefore doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue with decreasing default partition count 5 to 1. Somehow because of kafka version it can't decrease partition count but it can increase it.